# Re-render eyecon datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, render, onchange, eyecon-plugin

I have an issue with the eyecon datepicker (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker). I want it ('#date') to re-render (disabling different periods) each time I change the value on the select ('#room').

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var openDays = <?php echo json_encode($area_open_days); ?>;
$('#room').change(function(){
    var room = $(this).val();
    $("#date").datepicker({
        onRender: function (date) {
            if(openDays[room][date.getDay()] == 1)
                return '';
            else
                return 'disabled';
        }
    }).data('datepicker');
});
});
```

Outside of the $('#room').change the code works, but of course doesn't update when I select a new value, so I think I need to re-render the datepicker... any help? Thanks!

Comment: What is `#room` in this context?

Comment: In the html context is the id of the select. In a more general context is a room to book which has its own availability (which defines the disabled periods on the datepicker).